# How to make XMLHttpRequest cross-domain withCredentials, HTTP Authorization (CORS)?

Tags: http, xmlhttprequest, cors

I'm unable to make a cross-domain request with an Authorization header (testing with Firefox). I have requests working without authentication, but once I set `withCredentials` to true I am no longer able to read the response from the server.

On the server I send back these headers (using an `after_request` method in Flask):

```
resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'
resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, OPTIONS'
resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Authorization'
```

*No OPTIONS call is ever actually made by Firefox*. On the client I make an XMLHttpRequest call:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open( 'POST', 'http://test.local:8002/test/upload', true)
xhr.withCredentials = true
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log( xhr.status, xhr.statusText )
}
xhr.send(fd)
```

Without `withCredentials` set the log statement will log the expecting information to the console. Once I set the value however the xhr doesn't allow access and I just write a 0 value and an empty string. I haven't set the authorization header here, but that shouldn't affect my ability to read the result.

If I attempt to add a username/password to the "open" command I get a `NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied` error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

*I've [written an article](http://mortoray.com/2014/04/09/allowing-unlimited-access-with-cors/) with a complete CORS setup.*

I found several issues that can result in this problem:

1. The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` cannot be a wildcard if credentials are being used. It's easiest just to copy the `Origin` header of the request to this field. It's entirely unclear why the standard would disallow a wildcard.
2. Firefox caches the Access-Control results even if you clear the cache (perhaps for the session). Restarting forced it to do a new `OPTIONS` request. To aid in debugging I added the header `Access-Control-Max-Age: 1`
3. The username/password of the `open` command is apparently not usable as the credentials. You must add an `Authorization` header yourself. `xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa( user + ':' + pass ) )`

Overall the `withCredentials` system is rather braindead. It's easier to simply write a server that accepts the authorization as part of the body of the request.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've been struggling with CORS and user authorization for the past week. Once I read your answer, I decided to do my own user authorization. Works like a charm. Yes, "braindead" is a very apt description.

Comment: Note that point 1 "copying the `Origin` header to `Access-Control` response headers" requires you to validate and sanitize that header, and checking against a whitelist of allowed origins (unless you really meant Access-Control-Allow=* with credentials, but nobody would want such a thing) . On the other hand, blindly copying an Origin may introduce serious vulnerabilities, and copying a valid Origin using string-unsafe mechanisms may also do so.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I found that works with [preflight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) requests is:

- Disable autentication for OPTIONS method requets by moving autentication logic to code (e.g. from Apache to PHP).
- Use jQuery `ajax` call with `withCredentials`:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    ...
});
```

Surprisingly, if I just set [xhr.withCredentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) to `true` it doesn't work:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    beforeSend: function (jqxhr) {
        jqxhr.withCredentials = true; // This doesn't work
    },
    ...
});
```