# Xampp Access-Control-Allow-Origin error

Tags: javascript, xampp

I'm using `Xampp` server to access my video file and then play it on my website. I'm using a `XMLHttpRequest` to obtain the video file and then put it as the source of the video player. But I'm getting an error. I have tried to solve the problem by inserting `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` but I'm still not able to fix the problem. I have given my codes and the error below. Please Help Me.

Also I do not want any suggestion on alternative method of showing the video. I wish to use the `XMLHttpRequest`.

My sample code:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <video video-player width="640" height="360" controls></video>
    <script>
        var video_player = document.querySelectorAll('[video-player]')[0];

        // I ORIGINALLY USE MY http://localhost:8080/.... FOR THE 'var url' BUT FOR STACKOVERFLOW I'M USING THE LINK BELOW AS AN EXAMPLE 
        var url = "http://dash.akamaized.net/akamai/bbb/bbb_1280x720_60fps_6000k.mp4";
        
        request_xhr (url, function (buffer)
        {
            video_player.src = buffer;
        });

        function request_xhr (url, cb)
        {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
            xhr.withCredentials = true;
            xhr.open('get', url, true);
            xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
            xhr.onload = function ()
            {
                cb(xhr.response);
            };
            xhr.send();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My `.htaccess` in the directory `C:\xampp\htdocs\`:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

My error:
[image]

Comment: With credentials you'll also need `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true`

Comment: does changing `xhr.withCredentials = false;` help? (based on reading the error that should help) - if not, then you'll need to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response to be the same as the requests `Host` header - of course, test.html will have to be served using `http://` and not `file:///`

Comment: origin "null" suggests that the html page is loaded using `file:///`, and not `http://`?

Comment: one more thing, can `video_player.src` be set to an arraybuffer anyway?

Comment: @JaromandaX `xhr.withCredentials = false` doesn't work

Comment: @ippi I tried your method but still didn't work

Comment: Then I think @JaromandaX got it right. If you are opening your sample.html directly, just stop it and run it from your dev server instead (http://localhost/sample.html or similar).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you are using `withCredentials` then wildcard `*` can not be used as a value for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. You must set the host address of your website instead of `*`. Second reason is `Origin` being null, which means the web page is not served by actual server as mentioned in comments by Jaramonda.

Answer (score -1):

Use attribute in video element crossorigin and set its value to anonymous:

```
document.getElementById("videoPlayer").setAttribute("crossorigin", "anonymous");
```

Comment: since XHR fails before the src is set, this wont help

Comment: since its not a url its a blob url i guess because data is received in xhr as arraybuffer so video element does not play blob url unless its crossorigin is anonymous

Comment: did you try creating blob url from arraybuffer  video_player.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([new Uint8Array(buffer)]));

Answer (score -1):

Try to enable it by php

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Comment: what does php have to do with a video URL?

Comment: That would only work if OP was echoing out the resource from php there is no indication they are doing that

Comment: I can't use PHP file

Comment: You say using xampp, i guess that you render the file by php 

Comment: Using xampp server to get video file and picture. I'm able to receive the video file in my android app

Comment: By error message displayed, would it need a credentials to access the video?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850454/how-to-make-xmlhttprequest-cross-domain-withcredentials-http-authorization-cor hope this helps

Comment: @Moch.RizalRachmadani I got no clue to if credentials are required

Answer (score -1):

create blob url from arraybuffer like this

window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL
            request_xhr(url, function (buffer) {
                video_player.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([new Uint8Array(buffer)]));
            });

Comment: the `request_xhr` is getting an error = `[js] ';' expected` && `function request_xhr(url:any, cb:any):void`