# Cookies are not included when using withCredentials in XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies, xmlhttprequest

Here is my scenario:

I am making an ajax request from `foo.com` to `api.bar.com`. In the response, it sets some cookies using `Set-Cookie` header. The domain on the set-cookie header is `.bar.com`. I am using all steps listed here [How to make XMLHttpRequest cross-domain withCredentials, HTTP Authorization (CORS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21850454/3219798)

I am able to see and verify (using Chrome extension EditThisCookie) that cookies are being set properly for domain `.bar.com`.

According to my understanding, when I make an ajax request (using `withCredential:true`) to `cdn.bar.com`, , it should include the cookies that were set earlier for domain `.bar.com`.

These cookies do not get included in the request, I can see it in fiddler. What am I missing here?

**EDIT**

Cookies DO get included in the request header If I make a request to `cdn.bar.com` from an origin `app.bar.com`. The problem only appears when it's called from a different origin `foo.com`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the `SameSite` restriction of the cookie. If I change the it from `lax` to `No Restriction` then it works fine.