# Inconsistent Cookie Behavior with Axios withCredentials in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, http, cookies, axios, csrf

I'm working on a Vue.js frontend and have encountered an odd behavior regarding cookie transmission using Axios. I've set up a custom Axios instance with default configurations and an interceptor to append the CSRF token in headers. The setup is as follows:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import config from '@/config';

// Custom Axios instance
const customAxios = axios.create({
    baseURL: config.BASE,
    withCredentials: true // Global setting
});

// Axios interceptor to add CSRF token
customAxios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    // Interesting things happen
    // ...
    return config;
});
```

I use this custom instance across various API endpoint functions, like this:

```
export const userTrainingData = async () => {
    return await customAxios.get(config.BASE_USER_TRAINING, { withCredentials: true });
};
```

Now, I've observed the following behavior:

Global `withCredentials`: When `withCredentials` is `true` in the Axios instance, and I don't specify it in the endpoint function, all cookies (sessionid and csrftoken) are sent as expected.

Local `withCredentials`: When I remove the global `withCredentials` and only specify it in the individual endpoint function, only the csrftoken cookie is sent, but the sessionid cookie is missing. This occurs consistently across different browsers.

Headers are all correct (I've checked in the dev tools, access control, path, all of the required ones), and the rest of the application behaves as expected. It's just this specific discrepancy based on where `withCredentials` is defined that's weird.

Could anyone explain why this might be happening? Is this expected behavior with Axios, or might there be something I'm overlooking with cookie settings or Axios configuration? Any insights or similar experiences would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: withCredentialsA, I think, also requires that you have set CORS properly. Have you configured it properly? Are you using HTTP or HTTPS? also add how you set the cookie to your question.

Comment: Yup, cookie settings are done in the backend - all of that works and set up the way I need it to work. All the required headers are present in the request and response. Using HTTPS, so secure flag is set, as is httponly, along with SameSite being set to None. 

The issue is specifically with where 'withCredentials' is mentioned. What did you mean by how I set the cookie? The set-cookie flag is in the header.

Comment: have you configured CORS? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850454/how-to-make-xmlhttprequest-cross-domain-withcredentials-http-authorization-cor

Comment: @ToreNestenius yes, I have :)

Comment: The browser usually can give you some good clues about why cookies are blocked/rejected or not included, I did blog about it here at https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/ (the post is pretty generic)